# Windows remote desktop to a pc without a monitor? / Force windows to boot in VGA?

Tags: windows-xp, display, graphics-card, remote-desktop

I have an old pc with a broken graphics card. It can run on vga mode. So I decided to control it using remote desktop on my laptop. It worked. But I feel like Im wasting the monitor of that broken pc. So can I still control that old pc without its monitor?

Also, since i dont want to make another thread, how can I force start windows xp (the old pc) on vga mode? I dont want to press f8 when turning it on (especially if my first question is possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can take the monitor off the PC and use the remote client to control the PC.  F8 is your best bet to get the PC to start in VGA mode.  Do you have another graphics card you can throw in temporarily to get the PC to run?

Comment: I don't. My motherboard has an onboard graphics card but most of the time it doesnt work (windows wont startup). 
I dont wanna buy a new one cause im just waiting for my new pc to be shipped.

F8 is the only way? Well thats too bad. Is there keyboard shorcuts for it cause since you said plugging in a monitor isnt required... I wont use my monitor for that old pc.

Comment: Then it looks like you can remote in until the new PC arrives.  Out of curiosity, why do you want to boot in VGA mode?

Comment: Because its not starting up when I boot it in normal mode. My graphics card is broken remember? So it just blinks when booted normally. Edit: hold on. I just realized something. When I boot it normally, theres no display.. but it seems like it still runs.. Then why do i have to boot it in vga mode when I'll remotely control it anyway?

Comment: You don't have to boot to VGA to control it remotely, that's why I asked :).  You should be fine to remote in until the new PC arrives.

Comment: Yeah sorry. But im not sure though because my pc acts strange when booted in normal mode. Its just blank screen and the monitor turns on and off. And the keyboard lights are lighting on and off too.

Comment: If you can remote in and the machine does what you want it to, don't worry about the LEDs on the keyboard.  The monitor may act strange, given your trouble with the display anyway, but if you take the monitor off, that won't be a problem anyway.

Comment: Ok i will try to boot it in normal mode then try to access it remotely. Hope it works. Thanks.